# Uploaded File Validation with 8 Bit Binary

Tags: angular, file, validation, upload

Im trying to validate a file upload in Angular. I want to allow files only with extensions .txt, .xls, .xlsx.

I acheived that with extension checks. But, If i change the extension of a .exe file to .txt, I can still upload the file. I believe that I have to check for the first 8 bits of the binary of the file Im uploading to validate it's type rather than validating it's extension.

Please guide me on how to do the same.

```
 fileConfiguration: any = {
    notAllowedCharactersForFileUpload: '({}[]!@#^&*',
    transactionFileSize: 5,
    fileTypeForTransactionDoc: 'application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,text/plain',
    fileTypeForSupportingDoc: 'image/jpeg,image/png,image/png,application/pdf',
  };
```

Here, I am mentioning the file types.

```
 onFileUploaded(file: any): void {

    if (
      !this.fileConfiguration.fileTypeForTransactionDoc
        .split(',')
        .includes(file[0].type)
    ) {
      this.toasterService.showToaster({
        severity: 'error',
        detail: 'Only *.xls, *.xlsx & *.txt file formats allowed',
      });
    } else if (this.isFileCOntainsSpecialCharacter(file[0].name)) {
      this.toasterService.showToaster({
        severity: 'error',
        detail: `Characters ${this.fileConfiguration.notAllowedCharactersForFileUpload} are not allowed in file name`,
      });
    }
    else if (
      file[0].size >
      +this.fileConfiguration.transactionFileSize * 1024 * 1024
    ) {
      this.toasterService.showToaster({
        severity: 'error',
        detail:
          'File Size should be less than ' +
          this.fileConfiguration.transactionFileSize +
          'Mb',
      });
    }
    else {
      this.uploadFileAPI(file)
    }
  }
```

Here Im validating the same.

Comment: Why do you want to read the file ? That is actually rarely done. The frontend checks the "easy to spot" errors. Can you tell us more why you want such a safe upload ?